# How to change the current array format to just an array of objects format?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How can I change the following data structure that is coming from the api into the desired format that is defined below?

```
inspectionViewAllRs = [
  {
    INSPN_XFER_SEQ_NR: {
      value: '5'
    },
    FNRL_FLG: {
      label: 'No',
      value: 'N'
    },
    HAS_PAST_INSPN: {
      value: '3'
    },
    MTG_CO_PHN_AREA_CD: {
      value: ''
    },
    DECLARATION_CD: {
      label: 'US Citizen/Non-Citizen National',
      value: 'CZ'
    },
    ....
    ....
    ....
  },
  { ... }
  { ... }
  { ... }
]
```

How can I just convert it into this an array of objects format?

```
inspectionViewAllRs = [
  { label: "", value: '5' },
  { label: "No", value: "N" },
  { label: "", value: "3" },
  { label: "", value: "" },
  { label: "US Citizen/Non-Citizen National", value: "CZ" },
  ....
  ....
  ....
]
```

I tried to do the following but this doesn't help much:

```
    if(!_.isEmpty(this.state.inspectionViewAllRsData)) {
  const result = this.state.inspectionViewAllRsData.map((data, i) => {
    const items = Object.values(data);
    const newItem = {}
    newItem.label = items[i].label;
    newItem.value = items[i].value;
    
    return newItem
  })

  console.log("result ", result)
  
  // this is what I see printed out in console log
  // result (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
              0: {label: undefined, value: "5"}
              1: {label: "No", value: "N"}
              2: {label: undefined, value: "3"}
              3: {label: undefined, value: ""}
              4: {label: "", value: ""}
              length: 5
}
```

Why am I not getting return all the rest of the data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [`Object#values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get one list of the objects values, and then [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the same attributes in all:

```js
const inspectionViewAllRs = [
  {
    INSPN_XFER_SEQ_NR: { value: '5' },
    FNRL_FLG: { label: 'No', value: 'N' },
    HAS_PAST_INSPN: { value: '3' },
    MTG_CO_PHN_AREA_CD: { value: '' },
    DECLARATION_CD: { label: 'US Citizen/Non-Citizen National', value: 'CZ' },
  },
  {
    DECLARATION_CD: { label: 'US Citizen/Non-Citizen National', value: 'CZ' },
  }
];

const res = inspectionViewAllRs
  .flatMap(Object.values) // get one list of objects
  .map(({ label = '', value = '' }) => ({ label, value })); // return list of label/value objects

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much Majed.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `.flatMap` and map on the items `.values`.

You API repsonse looks like:

```
[
{ unneeded_keys: Needed_Values}, //objectOfData
{ unneeded_keys: Needed_Values},
{ unneeded_keys: Needed_Values},
]
```

Your `state.inspectionViewAllRsData` array contains these objects. The actual data you need is inside `Needed_Values`.

So, you need to do:

```
 //                             Note: flatMap here \/\/\/
 const result = this.state.inspectionViewAllRsData.flatMap((objectOfData) => {
    const items = Object.values(data);
    return items.map((item, i) => {
       return {
           label: item.label ?? '', // handle case when label is undefined
           value: item.value,
        }
    }
    
  })
```

The reason you need to use `flatMap` is because each obj in your API response, will return multiple elements as per your transformed data. So, flatMap will automatically flatten the array of array of objects to array of objects.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation Vinay. I really appreciate it.